# How to properly package a mixed C/Swift library and include it as a module in an Xcode project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I tried building it as an Xcode Static Library project with the following structure:

- C source and header files (Folder)
- Bridging header
- Swift files

The Swift files detect the C code just fine, and the library is built correctly without it. I then wrapped iOS simulator and iOS builds into an XCFramework and tried to include it in a project but I can't do `import SampleModule`.

I have also put the "Defines Module" in build settings to "YES" and defined a *module.modulemap* file. Trying to build it then gave me:

```
<unknown>:0: error: using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
```